# How do I apply patches from a merge request?

Tags: composer, 9, community-official-site

I used the patch [#48](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-04-15/2897638-48.patch) of [Views exposed sort identifiers are not configurable](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2897638). I need to update the core, and apply the latest rebased version of that.

However, the issue hasn't be marked *Fixed*, and I don't see any "patch file" to link in my composer.json.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look into the Issue queue you can see MR #54 is the latest code change.

[image: MR #54]

Go to the URL of the MR and add **`.patch`** at the end of the URL you will get the path to the latest patch.

URL for your latest patch is [#54](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/merge_requests/54.patch)

**Note** : It is advised to download patch locally from merge request to avoid issues due to new commits on the same merge requests. As new merge commits are not always correct.

Comment: There are two different URL's for the merge request and they both produce the diff for composer.  e.g. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/-/merge_requests/8.patch and https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/-/merge_requests/8/diffs.patch

Comment: **Important Note:** If someone commits to a merge request after you have included the patch, their changes will automatically be added to your codebase when you run `composer install`. The patch file is not guaranteed to stay the same or always work.